# select string that does not contains sevaral words in php

Tags: php

I have a string in php

`$string = "a very long text ...."`

I would like to check if this string contains any of the following words

`$forbidden_words = array("word1", "word2", "word3");`

I know I can use

`if (str_contains('abc', '')) { .... }`

but this works for only one word. How can I select the string if does not contain any of the words in the array ?

Comment: Do any of the provider answers work?

Answer (score 1):

You could form a regex alternation of the blacklisted keywords and then use `preg_match()`:

```php
$string = "a very long text ....";
$forbidden_words = array("word1", "word2", "word3");
$regex = "/\b(?:" . implode("|", $forbidden_words) . ")\b/";
if (!preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    echo "MATCH";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to iterate over the array of forbidden words and check if any of them exist:

```php
$string = "a very long text ....";
$forbidden_words = array("word1", "word2", "word3");

foreach ($forbidden_words as $word) {
    if (str_contains($string, $word)) {
        echo "The string contains the word: $word";
    }
}
```

Alternative to check if any of them appear in the string (using `strpos`) :

```php
$string = "a very long text ....";
$forbidden_words = array("word1", "word2", "word3");
$contains_forbidden_word = false;

foreach ($forbidden_words as $word) {
    if (strpos($string, $word) !== false) {
        $contains_forbidden_word = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$contains_forbidden_word) {
    // The string does not contain any of the forbidden words
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to check for all the words in one run.

```
$forbidden_words = array("word1", "word2", "word3");
$string = "a very long text ....";
if(preg_match('/\b(' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $forbidden_words)) .  ')\b/')) {
    echo 'have forbidden word(s)';
}
```

This uses word boundaries to ensure partial word matches don't match. In demo below `word1` won't match `word`, vice versa would occur with string functions (e.g. `strpos`). An `i` modifier can be added after closing delimiter if this should be case insensitive.

https://3v4l.org/Y4gTJ